# Optimize regex query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an query for MySQL that I'm trying to optimize. I have a table t with a few hundred thousand rows, with a varchar column x (and a few other) that is indexed and has less than 1000 distinct values. I'm trying to get all distinct x that match a specific regex. This is the straight forward way to formulate this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x 
FROM t
WHERE x REGEXP 'someregexp'
```

But it seems like MySQL totally disregards the index when using REGEXP, so it takes a few seconds. Since I have a pretty low number of distinct values, it should be pretty fast to process this if the query fetches the distinct values using the index and then filters that result using the regex, but this doesn't seem to be the case right now, because it should be able to run in less than a second.

Is there any way I can hint to the MySQL query optimizer that it can do it that way?

Comment: "is indexed" -- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT d.x
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM t) d
WHERE d.x REGEXP 'someregexp'
```

This way it should first do the distinct filtering (which is fast with indexes) and then do the regexp (which is fast if it only has to be done on a few distinct values).

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A:**

```
SELECT x
    FROM t
    GROUP BY x
    HAVING x REGEXP 'someregexp';
```

(This does not need to write, and read, a temp table, as the subquery approach does.)

**Plan B:**  Add `INDEX(x)` and have a new enough version of MySQL such that it can leapfrog through the index.  (See MRR, perhaps in 5.6.10.)  Note: This helps the subquery approach, too.

**Plan C:**  Do both Plan A and Plan B.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if MySQL supports materialized views nor how 'welcome' this would be as I fear they might slow down changes to your table dramatically (**). However, I do think you might get away with a summary table that holds the distinct values you're after combined with a couple of triggers on the base table that will maintain the summary table.
(on INSERT you only need to add the ones you don't have yet in the summary table, on DELETE you'd have to check if you deleted the last one and if so if remove it from the summary table too. On UPDATE you'd have to check for both).

Given the indexes you already have, this shouldn't be too cumbersome IMHO, and since you only have about a 1000 values in that summary table I expect the regexp to be much quicker too.

(**: depends a lot on how "smart" this thing is, if your "view" is fully refreshed with every change to the base table then I doubt this will be acceptable)